# How to use Map<K, V> with string and int in Cocos2dx-v3 C++?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Map%3CKV%3E

This link only explains with

```
Map<std::string, Sprite*>
```

types.

If I want to use something like this:

```
 Map<std::string, int>
```

should I just stick to std::map?

Will I have to do some extra memory management if I use std::map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should I just stick to `std::map`?

Yes.

> Will I have to do some extra memory management if I use `std::map`?

No.